# How to retrieve specific fields from observable stream?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have created Following Observable Stream which holds User Object.

```
currentUserProfile$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserProfile>(null);
```

To Initialise this stream I have defined the method below:

```
getCurrentUserProfile(userId):void{
    let profile:UserProfile= new UserProfile({});
    this._empService.getUserInfo(userId).subscribe(
        (response)=>{
          profile=response.profileData;
          profile.isAuthenticated=true;
          this.currentUserProfile$.next(profile); 
        },
        (error)=>{
          profile.isAuthenticated=true;
          this.currentUserProfile$.next(profile);
          console.error(error);
        }
    );
}
```

Now I want to create methods For Each of those attributes that stream contains. for ex.

```
getUserRole(){
    let roles:Array<any>;
    this.currentUserProfile$.subscribe((profile:UserProfile)=>{
      roles=profile.roles;
    });
    return roles;
}

hasRole(role:string):boolean{
    let res:boolean;
    this.currentUserProfile$.subscribe(
      (profile)=>{
        res=profile.roles.indexOf(role) !== -1;
      }
    );
    return res;
}
```

Is there any easier way than this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather keep observable as is, and them apply some transformation over it

```
getUserRole(){
    return this.currentUserProfile.map((profile:UserProfile)=> profile.roles);
}

hasRole(role:string):boolean{
    return this.currentUserProfile$.reduce((role) => 
        profile.roles.indexOf(role) !== -1;
    );
}
```